# Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am getting the above problem with the below script in powershell.
I can't seem to find the issue. The script requires 2 parameters, and I've supplied them on the command line but it still throws an error?

**Command:**

```
PS C:\> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command installboot.ps1 -computername 192.168.162.1 -argumentlist MyServer\MyNewService, option2
```

**Script:**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $IISName, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $installmode
)

write-host "IISName: " $IISName
write-host "Install Mode: " $installmode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with the `-Command` parameter e.g.:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {invoke-command -file installboot.ps1 -computername 192.168.162.1 -argumentlist MyServer\MyNewService,option2}
```